# User control binding is not properly working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I kinda stuck on data-binding here. So, let's say I have a following `Class` :

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       

    public string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
    }

    public bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _isSelected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have a `UserControl` to visualize the class, with the following ViewModel :

**StudentVisualizerVM.cs**

```
public class StudentVisualizerVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Student _student;
    public Student Student
    {
        get { return _student; }
        set { _student = value ; NotifyPropertyChanged("Student"); }
    }

    public StudentVisualizerVM()
    {
        Student = new Student();
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I want to use the UserControl in my MainWindow.

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Student}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <c:StudentVisualizer/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And finally this is my MainWindow ViewModel look like :

**MainWindowVM.cs**

```
public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Student _student;
    public Student Student
    {
        get { return _student; }
        set { _student = value ; NotifyPropertyChanged("Student"); }
    }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        Student = new Student();
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `User Control` didn't shows up on `MainWindow` even though I had initialize the `Student` Property in `MainWindow`. Why? Isn't `MVVM User Control` automatically populate its ViewModel? Or maybe it's `StudentVisualizerVM` that I need to store in `MainWindowVM`, instead of the `Student` itself?

**Note That (Updated) :**

1. Above code is not the real one, it's just to simplify my project into the main problem.
2. Assume each XAML's `DataContext` has been attached correctly from the XAML.CS.
3. Why I need to do this? Because I need to detect if the window has been clicked outside the `StudentVisualizer` then `IsSelected` is set to false. (This property used for certain Command which need the `Student` to be selected.) - Something like Select-Deselect-esque actio.

Comment: As a side note to my answer, when binding fails, it's logged to Visual Studio's Output Window, so next time you have binding problems, be sure to check for it, it can save a lot of time and headaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemsControl` is for displaying a collection of items, therefore `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` has to bind to an `IEnumerable` property, while you just bind to a single element.

You want something like :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding StudentCollection}"

public IEnumerable<Student> StudentCollection 
{
    get { return new List<Student> { Student }; }
}
```

Now, should you really use an `ItemsControl` to display just one item.. that's another question and the answer would be : no.

Comment: Is there any other way similar (ItemsControl is not obligatory) to display just one item? Something like ItemControl (for single item). Because I've searched and found nothing (maybe I missed something)

Comment: Yes there is : `<c:StudentVisualizer DataContext="{Binding Student}"/>`

Comment: If I `DataContext="{Binding Student}"` I wonder why I got this kind of error : BindingExpression path error: 'Student' property not found on 'object'